# How to assign a specific URL to a specific variable to display the images from AWS server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've 6 (3+3) input with preview fields where a user can select the image to be uploaded to the server which in turn on selecting, it'll be displayed in the input field which is customised as shown in image.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fCiQ.png)

Now, in Rails, when an image is being displayed it has to be done in an order by checking the field. I've used 2 approaches which in-turn are failing to display when there is no image that is uploaded in between i.e, where there is a image in 1st, 2nd and 4th box, the 3rd box has to be empty. The used approaches are not leaving the 3rd box empty but when it checks the condition, if it fails, it is exiting.

Approaches are.
1st -

```
def get_image_urls(user)
    user_identifications = user.user_identifications.where(current_flag: true).order(:id_dl)
    urls = []
    keys = []
    if !user_identifications.empty? && !user_identifications.nil?
        user_identifications.each_with_index do |each_id, index|
            obj = S3_BUCKET.object(each_id.aws_key)
            urls << {each_id.id_dl=> obj.presigned_url(:get)}
            keys << {each_id.id_dl=> each_id.aws_key}
        end
    end
    return urls, keys
```

2nd -

```
def get_image_urls(user)
user_identifications = user.user_identifications.where(current_flag: true).order(:id_dl)
unless user_identifications[0].blank? && user_identifications[0].nil?
    if user_identifications[0].id_dl == "dl1"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[0].aws_key)
        aws_url1 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[0].aws_key}
    end
end
unless user_identifications[1].blank? && user_identifications[1].nil?
    if user_identifications[1].id_dl == "dl2"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[1].aws_key)
        aws_url2 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[1].aws_key}
    end
end
unless user_identifications[2].blank? && user_identifications[2].nil?
    if user_identifications[2].id_dl == "dl3"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[2].aws_key)
        aws_url3 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[2].aws_key}
    end
end
unless user_identifications[3].blank? && user_identifications[3].nil?
    if user_identifications[3].id_dl == "id1"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[3].aws_key)
        aws_url4 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[3].aws_key}
    end
end
unless user_identifications[4].blank? && user_identifications[4].nil?
    if user_identifications[4].id_dl == "id2"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[4].aws_key)
        aws_url5 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[4].aws_key}
    end
end
unless user_identifications[5].blank? && user_identifications[5].nil?
    if user_identifications[5].id_dl == "id3"
        obj = S3_BUCKET.object(user_identifications[5].aws_key)
        aws_url6 = {"url": obj.presigned_url(:get),"key": user_identifications[5].aws_key}
    end
end
return aws_url1, aws_url2, aws_url3, aws_url4, aws_url5, aws_url6
```

Now, how to check and display the images accurately from the AWS?
Any help will be much appreciated.